# how to reduce token total supply from Bep20?

Tags: cryptocurrency, bep20

I have created a Bep20 contract using Binance template you may find the template here: https://docs.bnbchain.org/docs/issue-BEP20
and now i want to reduce the total supply of token/burn token but i have not fund any function/method to reduce the total supply. Any one know how can i do this?
my contract address is : 0x667bA7b87F3863e5cE1dCd939637DFA17b0016A8

I have tried to transfer token on nulled address you can check the transaction but its not reducing the total supply.
I want to reduce my total supply.

Comment: Reducing the total supply of a BEP-20 token after deployment is not directly supported by the standard contract. You might consider implementing burn functionality or minting negative amounts to achieve this, but it requires careful coding and testing. Alternatively, you could deploy a new contract with the desired supply and handle token migration. Changing a deployed contract carries risks and complexities, so expert advice is advisable.

Answer (score 1):

Your contract doesn't implement any `public` nor `external` function capable of burning tokens, i.e. decreasing total supply.

Since the contract is already deployed, it's not possible to change its source code and to implement this function.

---

What you can do, is to update the code, and then deploy the changed code on a new address.

Your contract implements an `internal` function `_burn` (most likely from OpenZeppelin library) that can be called from within another function. But since it's an `internal` function, it cannot be called from outside the contract.

You can implement an external function that calls this internal one, effectively burning tokens.

```
contract BEP20Token is Context, IBEP20, Ownable {

    // callable only by the `owner` address
    // can burn tokens from any address specified in the argument
    function burn(address from, uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {
        _burn(from, amount);
    }

    // TODO rest of your code
}
```